# Converting float to currency Argentine Peso

Tags: javascript, currency, numeral.js

It seems that the Argentine Peso (ARS) notation for currency is complete the opposite from what the Dollar is in the US. The `,` is used as a decimal separator, and the `.` is used as a thousands separator.

- `1121` => `$1.121,00`
- `1000.5` => `$1.000,50`
- `85.72` =>  `$85,72`

I've looked into [`numeral`](http://numeraljs.com/) (`npm numeral js`) and I have not been able to convert a float to the currency format specified above.

Here's what I tried:

```
> numeral('87.75').format('$0.0,00')
'$87.7500'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0,0.00')
'$87.75'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0,00')
'$88'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0.00')
'$87.75'
> numeral('87.75').format('$00,00')
'$88'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0.00')
'$87.75'
> numeral('87.75').format('$00,00')
'$88'
> numeral('87.75').format('$00,00.00')
'$87.75'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0[.]0.00')
'$87.8'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0[.]0[.]00')
'$87.8'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0[.]0[,]00')
'$87.75'
> numeral('87.75').format('$0[,]0[,]00')
'$88'
```

These are all strings but that shouldn't effect the formatting.

Comment: Worst case you can always `replace` from a `toString`

Comment: I have no expertise in the field, but would [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) help?

Comment: It is not just currency, English locale uses dot as decimal separator and comma as thousands separator, while the rest of European languajes use the opposite notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own format. Scroll down the numeral.js documentation to 'Languages' section for an example on how to define delimiters.

```
numeral.language('es_ar', {
    delimiters: {
        thousands: '.',
        decimal: ','
    },
    currency: {
        symbol: '$'
    }
});

numeral.language('es_ar');

numeral(1087.76).format('$0,0.00')
> "$1.087,76"
```

Answer (score 1):

`toLocaleString` is likely the function you're looking for. You can [read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Here's an example of using it to format a number as currency for the Argentine Peso:

```
var value = 1234.56;
var result = value.toLocaleString('es-ar', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'ARS',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});

console.log(result); // Prints "$1.234,56"
```

Comment: I wanted something that would work on both server and browser. This is cool though, thanks.

Comment: This works on both (it's an ES5 feature), although browser support is limited to only modern browsers at the moment. (Notably, Safari doesn't have good support for it yet.)